# Does scaling computer resolution decrease video resolution?

Tags: macos, mac, video, resolution

I have a UHD TV connected to my Mac. I have set the resolution to highest which obviously makes everything on the screen look tiny and hard to work with. I used the 'Larger Text' scaling option on the Mac to make the situation better and it is much better now.

However, I was wondering if this scaling applies to videos too. If I'm streaming a 4k video from YouTube/Netflix or I'm playing a 4k video in VLC player, will the video be downscaled to match the desktop resolution or will it still play in 4k?

My goal is to try to have everything but videos scaled down. Can this be done?

Comment: This is very confusing. What resolution is your Mac? Are you mirroring the desktop to this TV?

Comment: No, I'm extending my screen on to the TV. I then have the default resolution of my Macbook's screen and the full UHD resolution on my TV. Then change the TV's resolution to the 'Larger Text' option in the Display Settings from the Macbook. This applies scaling to the text but I suspect it scales down videos too.